# Inject double ampersand operator

Tags: ruby

I have an inject call

```
[2,4,6].inject(true) { |res, val| res && val % 2 == 0 }
```

and want to send the `&&` operator to inject as in `inject(0, :+)`. How can I do that?

Comment: Injecting to _boolean_ value sounds weird for me. I would use smth like `.each { |e| break false if … }`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't because `&&` and `||`, unlike other operators, are not syntacic sugar for methods (i.e. there is no method called `&&` or `||`), so you can't reference them using a symbol.

However you can avoid using `inject` to compute the logical conjunction or disjunction of an array of boolean values, replacing it with `all?` or `any?` respectively, because for any array the following conditions hold:

```
ary.inject(true) { |res, b| res && b } == ary.all?
ary.inject(false) { |res, b| res || b } == ary.any?
```

So, for example, the code you posted could be rewritten as:

```
[2,4,6].map(&:even?).all?
# => true
```

**Update**: obviously my latter example is not the right way to express this computation, falsetru's answer is much faster:

```
require 'fruity'

compare(
  -> { (0..1000).map(&:even?).all? },
  -> { (0..1000).all?(&:even?) }
)
```

```
Running each test 1024 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
Code 2 is faster than Code 1 by 111x ± 10.0
```

Comment: So your assumptions for the initial value passed to inject are inconsisteny with what I wanted to accomplish: [].reduce(:any_method) == nil, so I was hoping to ary.reduce(:&&) to test for presence AND all true values. Trying to squeeze too much out of ruby's syntactic sugar I guess. ary.present? && ary.all? will have to do (was just hoping not to store a temp variable)

Answer (score 9):

How about using [`Enumerable#all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F)

```
[2,4,6].all? &:even?
# => true
[2,4,6,5].all? &:even?
# => false
```

If you want to use `inject`, you need to define an instance method.

```
class Object
  def is_even(val)
    self && val % 2 == 0
  end
end

[2,4,6].inject(true, :is_even) # => true
[1,2,4,6,5].inject(true, :is_even) # => false
```

Comment: Sorry, the example might have misled you, I don't want to check for even numbers in the inject, i want the && operator called repeatedly on a predicate, to give me a boolean result.

Answer (score 3):

'&&' is not a method, hence you can't inject it. However you can inject & method.

```
[2,4,6,5].map(&:even?).inject(true, :&)
```

Which will do the same

NOTE: This however should not be done, as it is extremely risky and might cause unexpected consequences (if run on collection containing at least one non-boolean (true, false, nil) value). You should always use `any?` or `all?` methods instead.

Comment: Just to clarify though you already know it: & and && are equivalent here only because the operands are booleans.

Answer (score 0):

`inject(0, :+)` would add all the elements of the array, regardless of what the content of the elements are (odd, even, etc).

If you want to `inject(true, &:&&)` (I know this doesn't work), your array should be an array of boolean values for your question to make sense, which would be the same as: `[true, false].all?`

**important:**
you can't pass both block arg and actual block which means you can't check if it's even inject an && at the same time.

If you insist, try this out:

```
[2,4,6].inject(true, & lambda { |x,y| x && y })
=> 6
```

This is the equivalent of what you're asking for (which I still don't totally understand)